# How to manipulate API response and assert with jasmine-node

Tags: node.js, automation, epoch, jasmine-node, frisby.js

I'm writing an API test driven by Jasmine-node/Frisby.js.
The response has an object that has some epoch time (unix time;13 digits). 
I need to assert that time against another epoch time value that is known. 
Now, I don't need to be exact on the millisecond - it is sufficient for me to assert the day, month and year.

Is there a way to manipulate the response timestamp, get only the day, month and year and compare to my baseline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Figured this one..**

Need to provide the response body to to an 
*after(function (err,res,body){

//Further processing here

})*

There, one can parse the body, get the epoch, do whatever manipulation required and do the proper assertion.
In my case it was

```
var actualTimestamp = moment(res.response.time).format("MMM Do, YYYY");
var expectedTimestamp = moment(parseInt(baselineTimestamp)).format("MMM Do, YYYY");
expect(actualTimestamp).toEqual(expectedTimestamp);
```